# How can I get returned value from JavaScript function that contain jQuery.get()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript method that call  JQuery.get() and i want to return value from itto callee function ..  the following is the code :

```
function CheckExistance(userName) {
        $.get(
            "JQueryPage.aspx", { name: userName },
             function(result) {
                 if (result == "1") {
                     value = true;
                 }
                 else if (result == "0") {
                     value = false;
                 }
                 else if (result == "error") {
                     value = false;
                 }
             }
        );                
        return value;
    }
```

i want `return value;` return the value setted in `get()` function ... i know that `get()` is asynchronous operation anf i want a solution to do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot "return" the value into the called function; because as you've realised, the AJAX call is asynchronous. Instead, you need to effectively delay the execution of the code that follows the AJAX call; by placing this code in the `callback` function instead.

What happens now, is that this code is executed when the AJAX request has completed, and the `value` is available.

```
function CheckExistance(userName, callback) {
        $.get(
            "JQueryPage.aspx", { name: userName },
             function(result) {
                 var value = false;

                 if (result == "1") {
                     value = true;
                 }


                 callback(value);
             }
        );                
    }
```

Then where your function might previously have been:

```
function validateUserName() {
    var input = $('someField').val();
    var isUnique = CheckExistance(input);

    if (isUnique) {
       // whatever
    } else {
       alert("This username is already taken");
    };
};
```

Should now be:

```
function validateUserName() {
    var input = $('someField').val();

    CheckExistance(input, function (isUnique) {
       if (isUnique) {
          // whatever
       } else {
          alert("This username is already taken");
       };
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response , that's what i need

Comment: sorry but i have another question related to this solution 
if i want in onClick event of button in which if result = false i prevent submit else do submit 
i do the function but it also executed before validateUserName() finished

Comment: i found a solution by replacing get by ajax like this
var isAvailable = false;
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "JQueryPage.aspx",
            data: "name=" + username,
            success: function(result) { ....

Comment: I would **strongly** suggest not using synchronous AJAX requests. The whole page locks up whilst the request is in progress. You cannot (without making the AJAX synchronous) return true/false from the AJAX request in time to return false from the `onClick` handler. You can either return false, then call `form.submit()` in the AJAX callback function, or simply do all this work on the server side.

Comment: but i can't do check onClick of submit button as asynchronous will not return value before check .. so how i can do with make it synchronized ?

Comment: You don't. You `return false` immediately when the user submits the form, then once the AJAX call has completed, you can call `theForm.submit()` (`$(formSelector).get(0).submit()`) in jQuery if you want to submit the form.

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple example that works perfectly

```
    function test() {
      return $.ajax({
      url: "/url/" + param,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'html',
      async: false
    }).responseText
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This *might* work;

```
function CheckExistance(userName) {
    var value
    $.get(
        "JQueryPage.aspx", { name: userName },
         function(result) {
             if (result == "1") {
                 value = true;
             }
             else if (result == "0") {
                 value = false;
             }
             else if (result == "error") {
                 value = false;
             }
         }
    );
while(value == undefined);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't. First, I bet you meant `value != undefined` and second, this will **block** the client. Then you could also do an synchronous call, this will definitely work but who in the world wants synchronous calls ;)

Comment: Your while loop won't work: `while (value === undefined) ; return value;` would work, but is probably the most undesirable solution.

Comment: @Felix: No, I forgot the semicolon. Oh, and the OP seemed to want a synchronous call.
@Matt: What benefit does `===` offer over `==`

Comment: @Eric: It doesn't. I was commenting on the missing semi colon.